# Non-template methods of a template class in .cpp file - Undefined reference?

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

I am aware that template functions must be defined in the header file, for some reason I forgot. However I believed that non-template functions, even if they belong to a template class, could be defined in a .cpp file. Is that allowed ? If not, why not ? Thank you :)

Comment: Uhm, all of a template class is template, even if it doesn't show in the method signature or in the code of a method; given that even the class layout generally depends from the template argument (so the generated code for a method where the template argument doesn't appear can differ between different template instantiations), defining when it's allowed to "pick out" single methods would just add more confusing rules to the standard. The simple solution of moving all template-invariant stuff to a base class seems to me a better alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what must be defined in headers/at point of use (unless an explicit instantiation somewhere else happens), are "templated entities". There is no term like this in C++ so far, but proposals are in flight to add it to the language, since many rules apply to "templated entities" rather than just to templates.

See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0391r0.html

The reason should be obvious. Just like templates, the members of templates can make use of the template parameters, so their source must be available for instantiation.

The trick to work around this for classes (if the member function does not use the template parameter) is to put the functions in a non-template base class and inherit that class from the class template.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So basically it's not possible to implement in a .cpp a non-template member function that does not use the template types, not because required informations are missing for the compiler, but only because of a C++ limitation, right ?

Comment: I think it is not only because of that. But because the compiler, when compiling the cpp file has no way to communicate to users of the template class mmeber that the function does not "use the template parameters" and has been compiled already. The users on call sites need to know this in order to call this function differently (i.e. not using a symbol name that includes the template argument encodings etc). And then there is the rules that would be required to be stated by the language when and when not such a function is considered to use the params. Does using "this" count?